# clang/gcc only generates fma with -ffast-math; why?

Tags: floating-point, dot-product, fma

On icc 19, a dot product compiles down to a loop over an fma instruction. On clang and gcc, the fma is only generated with `-ffast-math`.

However, `-ffast-math` breaks IEEE compliance, but the fma is perfectly compliant with IEEE-754 2008, so if I have to compile with `-ffast-math`, then I cause other problems.

Why don't gcc and clang generate fma instructions without `-ffast-math`?

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3fak84); compiler flags are `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512`, +- `-ffast-math`.

Comment: Why do you think FMA is compliant with IEEE-754? If a programmer writes `a*b+c` to mean perform an IEEE-754 multiplication followed by an IEEE-754 addition, that is not the same as `fma(a, b, c)`, which performs a multiplication followed by an addition as if the multiplication had infinite precision. Those two things produce different results in some cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Traditionally I associate "breaking IEEE compliance" with cutting corners to increase speed while decreasing accuracy. As the FMA is a standardized op in IEEE-754 2008 which increases accuracy over a multiplication then an add, then I had imagined it's perfectly compliant to compile `a*b+c` to an fma. But do you have a reference showing this interpretation is wrong?

Comment: IEEE-754 does not define a binding from programming languages to IEEE-754 operations. That is up to the language. C’s Annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic, and IEC 60559 is effectively IEEE 754) binds `*` and `+` to the IEC 60559/IEEE 754 multiply and add. So `a*b+c` must be two operations, a multiply and a separate add. It cannot be a fused multiply-add. C implementations that do not adopt Annex F tend to follow this. GCC and Clang appear to be doing so.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks, that's what I was looking for; want to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Have a look at this [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NVsGZY) instead. Note that `gcc` compiled the scalar function to `fma`, but didn't use `fma` where it inlined it. I'm not sure about the answer (suspect a questionable optimizer decision), I only know that the accepted answer is wrong. Using `fma` **is legal** depending on `FP_CONTRACT`.

Comment: Found the reason: [associativity of +](https://godbolt.org/z/83cqaaY11). Note that while `std::inner_product()` must conserve associativity of the `+` operator (because for floating-point `(a+b)+c == a+(b+c)` does not hold in general), `std::transform_reduce()` is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce)  to allow reassociation. To conclude: `fma()` is perfectly fine for the compiler to use, but `a+b+c+d` can't be implicitly rewritten to `(a+c)+(b+d)` by summing into different SIMD elements in the accumulator unless `-Ofast` or equivalent is used.

Answer (score 4):

Is it appropriate for a compiler to implement a dot product *written* as `dot({a,c}, {b,d}) := a*b + c*d` using fused multiply/add, giving fl(⋅ + fl(⋅)) as if it were written `fma(a,b, c*d)`?
Generally no!

Here are a couple of examples adapted from [lecture notes by W. Kahan on IEEE 754](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF#page=5):

- Suppose we want to evaluate a difference of squares ² − ².

  This can be written as a dot product `dot({x,y}, {-x,y}) = x*x - y*y`.
  This naive formulation is subject to catastrophic cancellation when  ≈ , but at least when  = , it reliably returns zero because fl(fl(²) − fl(²)) = fl(fl(²) − fl(²)) = fl(0) = 0.

  This could be computed instead with FMA as `fma(x,x, -y*y)`.
  But if  =  = fl(1.234) = 0x1.3be76c8b43958p+0 then the outcome is −1.3532e7b3d8ep−55 ≈ −3.352 × 10⁻¹⁷, in IEEE 754 binary64 arithmetic, rather than zero as we might have hoped.

  Not only is it nonzero, but it is *negative*, so if you try to take the square root downstream you will run into NaN even if you can guarantee upstream that  ≥ .

  (The factoring `(x + y)*(x - y)` does better to avoid intermediate catastrophic cancellation, of course, but this question was about evaluating dot products without additional assumptions.)
- Suppose we want to evaluate the complex product in rectangular coordinates ( + )⋅( + ) = ( − ) + ( + ).

  The imaginary part of this can be written as a dot product `dot({a,d}, {b,c}) = a*d + b*c`.
  It could be computed instead with FMA as `fma(a,d, b*c)`.

  You might expect product of a complex number  +  with its complex conjugate  −  to be real, zero imaginary part—and it does if computed with `a*d + b*c`, but not if computed with `fma(a,d, b*c)`.
  For example, if  = fl(1.234) = 1.3be76c8b43958p+0 and  = fl(5.678) = 1.6b645a1cac083p+2, then fl(⋅(−) + fl(⋅)) = −1.6f6512a94ffp−55 ≈ 3.983 × 10⁻¹⁷.

So it would be poor form of a compiler to use FMA in these scenarios without your explicitly asking for it either by writing `fma(a,b, c*d)` with the `fma` function from `<math.h>`, or by adding `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON` to authorize such shenanigans.

---

That said…
It does not appear to be difficult to [persuade GCC 10.2 to abuse vfmadd231sd](https://godbolt.org/z/GTq5jW) simply by passing `-O2 -march=haswell`, even with an explicit `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT OFF`, and [same for ICC 21.1.9](https://godbolt.org/z/8xre5Y).
This looks to me like a buggy optimizer!
In contrast, [Clang 11.0.1 uses vfmadd231sd with `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON`](https://godbolt.org/z/c3aP77), but not with the pragma omitted or set to `OFF`.

Comment: Note that the question was specifically about a dot product.

Comment: @user14717 I rephrased it about dot products; is that clearer?

Comment: No, you've restricted yourself to length 2 vectors. Consider (as is traditional) the length-n vector.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know you're never going to use your dot product to implement these and that you don't care about the properties FMA would violate.   The semantics substantively changes if you rewrite `x*y + a` as `fma(x,y,a)`—and doing that willynilly leads to surprising trouble, which is why `fma` and options like `FP_CONTRACT` and `-ffast-math` exist.